# A resource named jms/ressource.factory already exists

Tags: glassfish, jms, payara

I get this error when i try to create a new JMS ressource :

> A resource named jms/cache.erpSSO.factory already exists.

[image: ressource jms exist]

But i'm sure that the ressource not exist, i test with

```
[glassfish@F-das ~]$ asadmin list-jms-resources
jms/sifc
jms/cache.harmoSSO
jms/suivi
jms/cache.moduleSSO
jms/sifcFactory
jms/cache.harmoSSO.factory
jms/suiviFactory
jms/cache.moduleSSO.factory
Command list-jms-resources executed successfully.
```

I restart the server and i still get the same error.

Someone have an idea about that?

Thank you.